# Is it always possible to reach a Wandering Box?

Tags: etrian-mystery-dungeon

The timer on wandering boxes seem to start whenever you enter a room. Are they always set so that a perfect or next to perfect beeline will earn you the item? Or are some just not possible to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Ninja skill called Headstart that, at level one, allows the Ninja to move 5 squares in one turn. Other than that, it's always possible to reach a wandering box in the allotted turns from any room, but sometimes you'll need to enter from the correct entrance, or there could be enemies in the way.

Comment: Does the countdown only go when you are in the room? Or does it start as soon as you enter and if you are at the wrong entrance you miss out?

Comment: The countdown starts the moment you enter the room, and will continue even if you leave the room.

Comment: I guess I will just need to keep in mind to look for wandering boxes before entering rooms now.